# what dose @sil_stored in Swift SIL mean?

Tags: swift

## @sil_stored

convert a struct define into SIL, got `@sil_stored`, what does it mean?

Can't find defines in SIL documents

origin swift code is

```
struct Constant {
    static let aCons = "haha"
}
```

using `swiftc -emit-silgen test.swift -Onone > test.swift.sil` got .SIL file, and at the file beginning

```
struct Constant {
  @sil_stored static let aCons: String
  init()
}
```

swift SIL doc is here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/SIL.rst

---

Additional Info.

```
enum Constant {
    static let aCons = "haha"
}
```

will be

```
enum Constant {
  static let aCons: String
}
```

looks a little simpler than `struct`

Comment: I am not familiar with the Swift compiler internals, but my *guess* would be that it marks a stored property (and not a computed property).

Comment: @MartinR I add a static property in a `enum`, there is not `@sil_stored`

Comment: I have no idea! – You could try to ask at https://forums.swift.org .